# WORDPRESS XAMPP permalinks not works

Tags: wordpress, xampp

I run Wordpress on my XAMPP but when I want to change the permalinks from default to post it just does not work correctly.

When I click my page, it says `No object found`, how cam i solve this problem ? thanks

Comment: Please show what you are doing and example code of same. This question is very vague.

Comment: This is not related to any code, so when I use Wordpress on my local server, XAMPP, after I change the permalinks from "default" to "post", the pages on my website can not be load up. I did some research and some people say it is because my rewrite module did not start, but I checked mine it has already been active, so idk what should I do now?